# How can I obtain from which Main Route I came from when using Nested Navigation in Jetpack Compose (NavHost)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using the `AnimatedNavHost` component in my Jetpack Compose app to manage navigation between different composable routes. I have added multiple navigation blocks to the `AnimatedNavHost`, and I want to obtain the `route` (it came from) of a specific navigation block.

For example, I have the following NavHost set up in my app:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun NavGraph() {

    val navControl = rememberAnimatedNavController()

    AnimatedNavHost(
        navController = navControl,
        startDestination = "home",
    ) {

        navigation(
            route = "home",
            startDestination = "site1home",
        ) {
            composable(
                route = "site1home",
            ) {
            }

            composable(
                route = "site2home",
            ) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I obtain the `route` of the `HomeRoute`? I want to be able to access the `route` of each individual navigation block.

### Example

My current Destination is "site1home" (API call for this `navController.currentDestination?.route`) is there a way to obtain from which [nested graph](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav) main route I came from (in this example the main route is "home") so I can display it like this.

[image]

I have tried to read the [NavController Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController) without success.

TLDR: Is there a `GetNestedGraphMainRouteOfCurrentDestination` function :D

Comment: You can use something like: val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()  
val mainRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.parent?.route (inside composable where you want to get parent route)

Comment: this works if you want to formulate an answer with a quick explanation I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Navcontroller's backStackEntry to get the main route of the navigation.
**currentBackStackEntryAsState()** gets the current navigation back stack entry as a MutableState. When the given navController changes the back stack due to a NavController.navigate or NavController.popBackStack this will trigger a recompose and return the top entry on the back stack.
Below is the sample block for the same.

```
@Composable
fun Site1(navController: NavHostController) {
   val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
   val mainRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.parent?.route
   Text(text = mainRoute)
}
```

The above code will show text as **home**